# How can I block this traffic I see in wireshark?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

I have an application running on my Amazon EC2 hosted windows Server-2012. The application listens for devices to connect to it on a number of ports. This application (known as s.exe) on occation sends information back (outgoing) to the devices connected to it. I would like to stop this outbound traffic from s.exe as it is un-nessisary. I cannot remove all outgoing traffic from s.exe because it must connect to a remote mysql database.

I've been trying to block this outgoing traffic from my server to these remote devices but I cant no matter what i try. Windows firewall didn't work, nor any of the third party firewalls I have tried. In wireshark and in TCPView I still see this outgoing traffic.

The outgoing traffic is coming from one application (in the images it is labeled "s.exe" over local port 11600 to a number of different remote ports.

Image 1:
[image]

[Click here to enlarge](http://postimg.org/image/annxec75t/)
[image]

I have attempted to block all outgoing traffic from local port 11600 but it has no affect at all, with windows firewall or outpost pro firewall.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It may not be possible. Most firewalls (and I'm assuming Windows Firewall works the same) apply outbound rules to traffic originating from the machine. In your case the outbound traffic isn't originating from the machine, it's actually the return traffic to the external machine that originated the connection that is allowed by your inbound rule.

Comment: Because its just return traffic it doesn't qualify as outbound?

Comment: It is outbound traffic but the outbound rules apply to outbound traffic that originates from the machine. In your case this outbound traffic isn't originating from the machine.

Comment: Not to beat a dead horse, and i appreciate the help, but is there any way at all to block this traffic? A global outbound rule? My only limitation is that it is a remote server so i cant use any type of hardware

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea. Hopefully someone smarter than me will chime in on your question.

Comment: Well either way I appreciate the help!

Comment: Block incoming connections to port 11600

Comment: I can't, incoming connections to port 11600 are necessary

Comment: If you have incoming TCP connections to port 11600, you can't block traffic going out from that port (if firewall worked as you expect), it would make your incoming connections useless as there would be no response, right?

Comment: Not really, i dont need to respond. All that is happening is that devices are sending location data through port 11600 to that application. The server/application should not and doesn't need to ever respond. It is a one way communication

Comment: I don't think you would be even able to establish TCP connection and send anything. Are you sure that traffic you want to block is really unwanted?

Comment: TCP is never "one-way communication". If you want to accept incoming data and not provide any ACK or outgoing packets, you'll have to use some other protocol, probably UDP.

Comment: @mpez0 Thanks, after doing research i want to switch the devices to UDP (which is possible) but i cant configure the server application to listen for UDP traffic. Is there any way to convert the UDP traffic to TCP on the server? So that the application never knows the difference

Comment: Peter, maybe you should open another question for that, with proper title (it would increase chance of finding solution)

Comment: Ummm. no. TCP and UDP are totally separate protocols and the applications on both ends would have to be redesigned and rewritten to use another protocol.

Comment: It is a long shot but it might work. With netcat you can redirect from udp to tcp, byte in, byte out...

Comment: @dusan.bajic Think i could get a link?

Comment: http://nmap.org/ncat, syntax is something like: ncat.exe --listen -u 11600 | ncat.exe localhost 11600 (but really, you shoud fix whatever problem you have properly, not this way)

Comment: @Peter - See? Smarter people did show up! :)